# Stationary Object in flat spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

Given an object in flat spacetime, far removed from gravitational sources,  is it possible for that object to be stationary with respect to itself?

Comment: Not clear what you mean maybe, but as best I understand your question every object is stationary with respect to itself.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

Every object is stationary with respect to itself at all times. Spacetime does not need to be flat etc.